# Core Data iCloud does not populate tableview until second launch

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have created an app that utilizes Core Data with iCloud. It seems that I have all the difficult pieces working correctly but am missing something really important. Once installed on two physical devices, changes on one appear as expected on the second. The issue is that I must install the app, then close it and relaunch it before ANY data appears in the main tableview. Xcode 6.3.1 iOS 8.3

This is true for each device. When the app has been deleted from both devices, I install the app on one device. I receive this on the console:

> 2015-05-04 15:33:05.297 BiopLogCloud[1353:734999]
>   -PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:: CoreData:  Ubiquity: 
>   mobile~C1432E0B-D885-418C-996C-5E6CDD45D7F1:BiopLogCloudStore Using
>   local storage: 1 The count is 0 inside persistentStoreDidChange inside
>   persistentStoreDidChange inside persistentStoreDidChange inside
>   persistentStoreDidChange inside persistentStoreDidChange inside
>   persistentStoreDidChange inside persistentStoreDidChange inside
>   persistentStoreWillChange inside persistentStoreDidChange 2015-05-04
>   15:33:06.979 BiopLogCloud[1353:735018]
>   -PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:: CoreData:  Ubiquity: 
>   mobile~C1432E0B-D885-418C-996C-5E6CDD45D7F1:BiopLogCloudStore Using
>   local storage: 0

Note the count variable - at zero. Then I relaunch the app and the
data is present. It does not matter whether I Build and Run from Xcode
or simply launch the app from the device. The data appears instantly
and if launched from Xcode I receive the following in the console:

> 2015-05-04 15:35:03.542 BiopLogCloud[1358:735588]
>   -PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:: CoreData:  Ubiquity: 
>   mobile~C1432E0B-D885-418C-996C-5E6CDD45D7F1:BiopLogCloudStore Using
>   local storage: 1 The count is 12 inside persistentStoreDidChange
>   2015-05-04 15:35:04.062 BiopLogCloud[1358:735625]
>   -PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:: CoreData:  Ubiquity: 
>   mobile~C1432E0B-D885-418C-996C-5E6CDD45D7F1:BiopLogCloudStore Using
>   local storage: 0

After repeating the same process on the second device the app works as expected.

Since it works after this initial issue, I'm not sure what code to show, but here is the relevant persistent store and fetched results code:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).last as! NSURL

    let storeURL = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("BiopLogCloud.sqlite")

    //if the store is incompatible
    //NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(url, error: nil)
    //nuke it

    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    let storeOptions = [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : "BiopLogCloudStore"]

    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: storeOptions, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data - cloud persistent store not created"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        // Remember to create an alert for the user in case of error
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {

    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        println("YES! You have found the issue - coordinator is nil")
        return nil 
    }

    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

    return managedObjectContext
}()

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {

    if myFetchedResultsController != nil {
        return myFetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

    // Edit the entity name as appropriate auto generate didn't work - fix that
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Patient", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50

    // Edit the sort keys as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateEntered", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "PatientCache")

    var countError : NSError? = nil
    var count = managedObjectContext.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &countError)
    println("The count is \(count)")

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    myFetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !myFetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
         abort()
    }

    return myFetchedResultsController!
}    
var myFetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

One scenario is that you're either not listening for `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` or not updating your table view when it arrives. That notification is how you know that new data has arrived from iCloud. If you don't handle it correctly, your app won't display any new data until you force it to reload its data-- such as by killing the app and re-launching it.

Comment: I do actually listen for this notification (in viewWillAppear) and do handle it, including a tableview reload. Once the app is "up and running" changes persist and are transferred among devices. It is ONLY with the initial load that no data is presented in the main tableview. There must be something in the initial installation that is handled differently. After a restart the app performs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled with this issue for an embarrassingly long time. It seems as though somewhere in the local creation process the table view controller thinks it has a good connection to the data when it really does not.

If you are using the standard xcode app for a tableview, fetched results controller and icloud I found that all I needed to do was place some code in the function called by the notification center when the stores change.

xcode sets a helper fetchedResultsController

```
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

If you set it to nil, then call for recreation of the fetchedResultsController you should be good to go. Again, the standard variable frc with modifications is what I use:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    ...bunch more code
}
```

So in the function I named handleStoresDidChange(..), nil the frc and recreate it

```
func handleStoresDidChange(notification : NSNotification) {

    print("storesDidChange notification:\(notification)")
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

    _fetchedResultsController = nil
    self.fetchedResultsController
    tableView.reloadData()

}//handleStoresDidChange
```

Hope that works for you.